# convert const float* into Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to convert  const float* array into Mat array in opencv 2.4.11 .
I tried this:

```
const float *svv = svm->get_support_vector(0);//this method returns const float*
cv::Mat sv= cv::Mat(1, sizeof(*svv), CV_32F, const_cast<float *>(svv));
```

It is useless. Any help with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
sizeof(*svv)
```

This does not give you the number of elements in the array; it gives you the size of the first element that `svv` points to. Since this is a `float`, `sizeof` gives you `4`.

You cannot tell the size of the array from a pointer to the array. You have to either know the length of the array and pass that value directly or use some array class.

Note that even if you had passed the array itself, `sizeof` still wouldn't have worked as it would give you the number of bytes in the array, not the number of elements.